# OData.ODataContentTypeException when trying to post via perl

Tags: 2013, rest, postback, linux

I fetch data from Sharepoint using perl on a linuxmachine. This worked real good as long as I only had to read data from there.

Now that I also have to change data on Sharepoint I'm stuck.

Sharepoint throws:

> A supported MIME type could not be found that matches the content type of the response. None of the supported type(s) 'application/atom+xml;type=entry, application/atom+xml, application/json;odata=verbose' matches the content type 'application/json'.

It's almost the same problem as this one, except that my Content-type seems to be correct and the error still gets thrown:

[ODataContentTypeException : Content Type 'application/json;odata=verbose'](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67692/odatacontenttypeexception-content-type-application-jsonodata-verbose)

After wasting two days with trying and googling I now hope that someone here can help me.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use LWP::UserAgent;
use LWP::Authen::Ntlm;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

# config
  my $host = "mysite.local";
  my $user = 'domain\spadmin';
  my $pass = "sucKmYducK";
  my $resource = "business/mytestsite";
  my $listid = "1bd8d1bc-e797-41ae-97c0-e3876406d0fe";
  my $itemindex = 20;

# globals
  my $digest;

# create useragent
  my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( keep_alive => 1);
  $ua->credentials("$host:443", "", $user, $pass);
  $ua->default_header('Accept' => "application/json;odata=verbose");
  $ua->timeout( 10 );

# get digest
  my $response = $ua->post( "https://$host/$resource/_api/contextinfo" );
  if ($response->is_success)
  {
    my $json = decode_json $response->decoded_content;
    $digest = $json->{d}->{GetContextWebInformation}->{FormDigestValue};
  }
  else
  {
    die $response->status_line;
  }

# post data
  my $msg = '{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.Data.DocLibItem"},"Title":"This is my testtitle"}';

  $ua->default_header
  (
    'Accept'          => "application/json;odata=verbose",
    'Content-type'    => "application/json;odata=verbose",
    'Content-length'  => length( $msg ),
    'X-HTTP-Method'   => "MERGE",
    'X-RequestDigest' => $digest,
    'IF-MATCH' => "*"
  );

  my $response = $ua->post
  (
    "https://$host/$resource/_api/lists('$listid')/items($itemindex)",
    {
      data => $msg
    }
  );

  my $json = decode_json $response->decoded_content;
  print Dumper( $json );

  if ($response->is_success)
  {
    print "place to be :)\n";
  }
  else
  {
    die $response->status_line;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging I could solve that problem.

The *default_header*-directive doesn't send the *content-type*-header. It is necessary to use the *HTTP::Request*-module to make it work.

Now Sharepoint accepts the post which brings me one step further, but not to the end since I now get a new error: *"Invalid JSON. A token was not recognized in the JSON content."*.

I'll post a new question for that...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use LWP::UserAgent;
use LWP::Authen::Ntlm;
use HTTP::Request::Common;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

# config
  my $host = "mysite.local";
  my $user = 'domain\spadmin';
  my $pass = "sucKmYducK";
  my $resource = "business/mytestsite";
  my $listid = "1bd8d1bc-e797-41ae-97c0-e3876406d0fe";
  my $itemindex = 20;

# globals
  my $digest;

# create useragent
  my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( keep_alive => 1);
  $ua->credentials("$host:443", "", $user, $pass);
  $ua->default_header('Accept' => "application/json;odata=verbose");
  $ua->timeout( 10 );

# get digest
  my $response = $ua->post( "https://$host/$resource/_api/contextinfo" );
  if ($response->is_success)
  {
    my $json = decode_json $response->decoded_content;
    $digest = $json->{d}->{GetContextWebInformation}->{FormDigestValue};
  }
  else
  {
    die $response->status_line;
  }

# post data
  my $msg = '{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.Data.DocLibItem"},"Title":"This is my testtitle"}';
  $msg = "";

  my $req = POST "https://$host/$resource/_api/lists('$listid')/items($itemindex)",
    "Content-type"     => "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "X-HTTP-Method"    => "MERGE",
    "X-RequestDigest"  => $digest,
    "IF-MATCH" => "*",
    "Content"  => { data => $msg };

  $response = $ua->request( $req );

  my $json = decode_json $response->decoded_content;
  print Dumper( $json );

  if ($response->is_success)
  {
    print "place to be :)\n";
  }
  else
  {
    die $response->status_line;
  }
```